# Highcharts/Highstock tooltip crosshairs appear on top of navigator when disabled

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to represent multi-series events on a timeline using a column chart in Highstock.

I want to completely disable the crosshairs that appear as you move the mouse around the chart.  It says quite clearly in [the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.crosshairs) that the crosshairs are disabled by simply setting `tooltip.crosshairs` to `false`.  However, after doing so the crosshairs still appear over the *navigator* portion of the chart.

[image]

jsFiddle: [jsFiddle showing problem](http://jsfiddle.net/whiletrue/s6BmC/9/)

Highcharts.stockChart configuration:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        alignTicks: true,
        animation: true,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        events: {
            load: function (e) {
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1398859200000, 1414753200000);
            }
        },
        ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
        renderTo: $('#chart')[0]
    },
    colors: [
        '#89f1a4',
        '#68d9f7',
        '#9eb9ef',
        '#c49eef'
    ],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true,
        navigation: {
            animation: true
        },
        shadow: false,
        verticalAlign: 'top'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: false,
        shared: true
    },
    navigator: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 10,
        maskFill: 'rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.7)',
        outlineWidth: 0,
        series: {
            type: 'column',
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInLegend: true,
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        max: 24,
        min: 0,
        ordinal: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%b %Y',
            month: '%b %Y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#ccc'
            }
        },
        minRange: 604800000,
        ordinal: false
    },
    series: data
});
```

**My question:**

I have been unable to find a "crosshairs" option anywhere in the Navigator configuration within the API documentation.  Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Which version HS do you use? Becuase in http://jsfiddle.net/wsVES/1/ works properly.

Comment: I'm using the same as that fiddle - v1.3.9 - but your one appears to exhibit the exact same thing.. are you seeing the crosshair over the Navigator (circled in image above) as you move your mouse around the data?

Comment: My bad I sent you wrong link, should be http://jsfiddle.net/wsVES/2/ which uses a master branch (beta) which fix this issue.

Comment: Ah, so its a known bug?

Comment: It was a bug, because not its fixed.